# Calculate the average using a cubic bezier spread

Tags: probability-distributions, cubics

[image: boobie graph]

I have values for minimum amount (a), middle amount (b), maximum amount (c), and a total count (Z). What I want to do is calculate the average amount (d) over that total min/mid/max spread, but with a cubic bezier curve (I think?) to spread the amounts around a kind of organic/non-linear representative range.

I don't have a math background (aside from programming), so I'm unsure of existing methods to spread the values over a range/max amount, nor how to adequately describe the problem.

An illustrated example: I have a $200$ events (Z), which can have between $10-2000$ attendees for each event (a-c). I want to weigh the middle point to the lower side, so I'll put it at $500$ (b).

$a = 10$

$b = 500$

$c = 2000$

$Z = 200$

Using the weighted bell curve, what would the average amount of attendees be to all the events?

***Edit:***

Based on JeanMarie's lead I looked into probability distribution.

I found something online which lead me to use this equation (sorry, I don't really know Math LaTeX notation):

$d = (a * Pa) + (b * Pb) + (c * Pc)$

$Pa$, $Pb$, $Pc$ equals the probability of each placement along the range. An applied example using the events as specified above (with estimated probability amounts) could be:

$d = (10 * 0.2) + (500 * 0.6) + (2000 * 0.2) = 702$

While this equation I can estimate a rough $d$ value, I don't feel it's entirely along the gauss/normalised distribution curve accounting for the variation/deviation in between. Is there a layman's equation that's a little more detailed to solve this?

Comment: The "bell curve" in statistics is not a Bezier curve but a Gauss curve.

Comment: Thanks for the lead! Just looking into normal distribution now

Comment: Now looking into probability distribution...